# Hot Reload not working in my PC, (vite React, CRA, live server) but none of them work

Tags: create-react-app, hot-reload, react-hot-loader, liveserver, vite-reactjs

i have tried all technologies that use hot reload (vite React, CRA, live server) but none of them work.

I also compared it with my other laptop, with all browser settings in sync, but it still doesn't work, I think the problem is with my PC

the point is, hot reload doesnt work in my PC